# How to add custom emoji in node-emoji (in node module)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, emoji

I need to add custom emojis in node-emoji. i have image in png format and need to use it as emoji in my node project.

i have seen [this](https://github.com/omnidan/node-emoji/issues/7) article but not understood how i can proceed.

I am using arrow_forward  emoji in my project everything worked good and looks good. one fine day my customer want me to change the background color of arrow_forward (from blue to red) . Unfortunately this is not available in emojis.[image]

I have attached what i want. 
I am using below code for blue color background

```js
${ emoji.get('arrow_forward') } Let's Begin
```

Comment: Are you developing a console app or GUI app (Using electron sort of framework)?

Comment: You can't directly convert a png image to a custom emoji for node-emoji. 
 (https://github.com/omnidan/node-emoji/issues/7#issuecomment-170016200 (The link that you have mentioned)

Comment: @SudhakarRS i am developing chat-bot using Microsoft bot framework. Which will be deployed in web. Correct Sudhakar, we cannot directly convert png to custom emojis. Thanks for your help. Cheers